# Can CString be an instance of IsString, Show?

Tags: haskell

There's

```
newCString :: String -> IO CString
peekCString :: CString -> IO String
```

And you need

```
fromString :: String -> a
show :: a -> String
```

My lame attempt

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeSynonymInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
{-# LANGUAGE OverlappingInstances #-}

module Main where

import Data.String
import Foreign.C.String
import System.IO.Unsafe

instance IsString CString where
  fromString = unsafePerformIO . newCString

instance {-# OVERLAPS #-} Show CString where
  show = unsafePerformIO . peekCString

mycs :: CString
mycs = "hello CString"

main = putStrLn $ show mycs
```

It seems to work. But, having never uttered `unsafePerformIO` before I wonder what kind of disaster I'm setting up here? Did I leak memory? Is there a safe approach to this convenience?

Comment: I suspect that this technique is unsafe, given that you have used `unsafePerformIO` *twice*. Generally every invocation of `unsafePerformIO` need to be strongly justified, preferably with a mathematical proof. I would hazard to guess from reading the type-class functions of `IsString` that `CString` is **not** an instance of `IsString` because `IsString` assumes the defined functions to be pure.

Answer (score 8):

No.  Your `show` function, for example, will return different results for the same `CString` value at different times.  This is because a `CString` is really a *mutable* string under the hood, equivalent to `IORef String`.  Because when an expression is evaluated and how many times an expression is evaluated are not specified by the Haskell language, an expression `show cs` using your instance will have a non-deterministic value, so *most* Haskell programmers would say this is not a valid use of `unsafePerformIO`, and it is (intentionally) not possible to implement `Show CString` without using `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 6):

This may be technically safe since you never ever change the memory pointed to by the `CString` value. Hence, the values are indeed immutable, and the effect of `unsafePerformIO` just mimicks a pure value.

*However*, the above holds only because *you never release memory*, and simply leak it every time you allocate a new string with `newCString`.

As soon as you fix the memory leak using `free`, then you lose safety: `unsafePerformIO` will read whatever is found at the old memory address. If you are lucky, this will crash the program. If you are unlucky, this will read garbage data into your strings. Good luck in debugging that.

I would strongly recommend against that approach.

TL;DR:

1. `unsafePerformIO` is unsafe, don't use it unless you know what you are doing.
2. C-like pointers such as `CString` should be used as little as possible, and only to interface with foreign languages.

Comment: Thanks. I am using it for FFI. The C layer uses `const char *` so shouldn't modify the strings. I want to find a way that doesn't leak to expose a haskell API which is straightforward and doesn't require users to litter their code with `withCString`, `free` or other memory management worries.

Comment: @MichaelFox, presumably you are already in the IO monad to call the C function via FFI, so you can just use `withCString`/`peekCString`/etc. in your Haskell API?